# Proguard issue with AndEngine GLES2 in Android-JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, proguard, andengine-gles-2

I have developed an app that uses [andEngine GLES2](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) and andEngine's extension [Physics2DBox](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension). The application has other functionality that doesn't just focus on the andEngine aspect. I have proguard enabled in my app. Now when I build a signed version of my app and navigate to where andEngine is used I get the following stack trace:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method    
"Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;.beginContact(J)V" at long 
com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(float, float, boolean) (World.java:-2) at void 
com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>(com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2, boolean 
(World.java:101)
at void org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init 
(com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2, boolean, int, int) (PhysicsWorld.java:61) 
at void org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init> . 
(com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2, boolean) (PhysicsWorld.java:57)
```

However, when I use a signed version of the app WITHOUT proguard, it works perfectly. So I know it is a proguard issue.

Currently, my app architecture looks like [image: this].

Where you can see that the libraries are modules to my app.

Currently, my proguard looks like this:

```
-dontobfuscate

-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

# Proguard configuration for Jackson 2.x (fasterxml package instead of codehaus package)
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
      public <methods>;
      protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep public class com.yelp.**

# Retrofit
-dontwarn okio.**
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# okhttp
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
#-dontwarn okio.**
#-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase


-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }



-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.**

-dontwarn org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
-dontwarn org.apache.log.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**

-keep class org.apache.http.**  { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.realm.**

-dontwarn com.stripe.android.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn com.nimbusds.jose.**

-keep class com.stripe.android.** { *; }
-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-keep class com.nimbusds.jose.** { *; }

-keep class com.zomato.photofilters.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers  class com.zomato.photofilters.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }

-ignorewarnings

# RULES FOR ANDENGINE STUFF
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class Loader {
    public static void main(...);
}
# note that <methods> means any method
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-optimizations!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# END OF RULES FOR ANDENGINE STUFF
```

With the andEngine GLES2 library and andEngine extension library having the following in their own Gradle files.

```
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it looks like proguard removes the World.class of the box2d extension. Try to add the following to your proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.** { *; }
```

So it will don´t touch your box2d files.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much, just added it to Proguard and doesn't cause a crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

---

https://libgdx.com/wiki/third-party/proguard-dexguard-and-libgdx

---

Add to ***proguard-rules.pro***:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```